# Move files from node.js to apache server

Tags: apache, heroku

Is there any possible for moving files from platform like Heroku to second server like Apache? I want to create application and push it to Heroku, but I have also Apache server and I want send to this server all images which I upload from frontend forms.

Comment: ? wait so you want to just move your files from one host to another? why not use git. do you have SSH access to either server? if not do you have FTP? more information please

Comment: i have ftp access to apache. I want create something like that: i have node api and application based on Heroku, and i have create something like image storage on apache server. Then in api i create in object (i want use mongo to store data) i create property with link to image which is stored in apache server. I dont know if my explain is good

Comment: I just updated my answer. i think thats what you are after.

Comment: Even if I use node/express api? My scenario will look like this: i want have (as You write) main application stored on Heroku, and i want create directory image on apache server. When i send form from application with image i want to send this image to image directory on apache.

Comment: the server that Serves up the files is the one that requires the security. it does not matter what type of web server it is (node,apache,nginx) - with my servers I keep the database and file server off the internet and only open to Lan requests and have the main load balancer on the same network with fire wall allocations. but i believe this might be a bit to advanced to explain. - you will require to run the api server on the one that serves the content. - if its not important information just serve it from http without api.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

ok so You want to use Heroku as the main application server. But then Heroku makes HTTP/HTTPS requests to the Apache server? 
I think thats what you are asking.

Yeah no issues with that. if you want to set up API id go with Laravel 5.3 and use its passport function on your Apache server ( but this is not required, this is only for security.)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport

**END OF EDIT**
what the web server is really does not matter at all.

Its about if the server has internet access and im pretty sure they do.

Easiest way is ftp,SSH,or git. unless they both have a web server then id just zip up your app without the node_modules folder and move it into the web directory. then go to the address of your server in a web browser. eg. http://mywebsite.com/files-i-just-zipped.zip and download them. (i normally log onto the new server via SSH and do wget http://mywebsite.com/files-i-just-zipped.zip)

I need more info but yeah. once you unzip then you need to install node but my guess is they already have it.

then do npm install in the package.json directory.